# In JavaScript, how do I change my regular expression to match all non-alphanumeric characters?

Tags: javascript, regex

My code is as follows:

```
"File name) - Title".match("[^ a-zA-Z\d\s:]")
```

At the moment, it matches ")" but I want it to match ") -", being the non alpha-numeric non-space characters between 'File name' and 'Title'

How do I change my regex to do this?

Comment: You can use \D which matches any non-digit

Comment: You included a space in your negated character set, so it doesn't match the space between `)` and `-`. Without more examples, it's pretty hard to say how one would reliably correct it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match ")" and "-" separately, use `g` flag

```
"File name) - Title".match(/[^ a-zA-Z\d\s:]/g)
```

If you want to match ") -" which is non-alphanumeric+space+non-alphanumeric,

```
"File name) - Title".match(/[^ a-zA-Z\d\s:]( )*[^ a-zA-Z\d\s:]/g)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/\s*(?:[^a-zA-Z\d\s:]\s*)+/
```

This regular expression matches optional leading spaces that are followed by one or more groups of non alphanumeric characters and optional trailing spaces. The question mark just means that what is captured within the round brackets is not saved as special component